# Mash a list together from some properties and a bit of logic

Tags: c#, string, list, linq

I need to mash a list of strings together using one or two properties from a list of objects, but dependant on a bit of logic. Each item in the list should be the string value of property 1 and property 2 joined together, separated by a hyphen. UNLESS property 1 has the same string value as property 2, in which case the item will simply be property 1. Just to clarify, all the objects are the same type and the two properties are both string values.

Here's an example to illustrate it just in case I didn't make sense..

```
Object 1: Prop 1 = "Object 1", Prop 2 = "Object 1" // Same value
Object 2: Prop 1 = "Object 2", Prop 2 = "Obj 2"    // Different
```

**Resulting list =**

```
[0] = "Object 1",
[1] = "Object 2-Obj 2"
```

Is there a "neat" way of doing that using a bit of Linq or something rather than looping through manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this?

```
var result = allItems.Select(
    item=>
    item.Prop1==item.Prop2
       ? item.Prop1
       : String.Format("{0}-{1}",
          item.Prop1, item.Prop2)
);
```

Comment: Yep that's it! Actually seems pretty straight forward looking at your answer, I thought It'd be a lot more complicated for some reason.. Thanks!

Comment: I was going to upvote, but I'll wait for you to fix the typos :P (shouldn't `item.Prop1==Prop2` be `item.Prop1==item.Prop2` ?). Also, I wonder if the `ToString()` serves any purpose: the question already mentioned that both properties are strings. And, just in case anyone wants it, here is the syntax-sugared version (add spaces at your leisure): `result = from item in allItems select item.Prop1==item.Prop2 ? item.Prop1 : String.Format("{0}-{1}", item.Prop1, item.Prop2)`

Comment: @w69rdy: if the answer sovles your problem, please make sure to mark the "tick" at the left margin to mark the answer as "Accepted", so the answerer gets credit and other people will see the question as answered.

Comment: @herenvardo Yep have done, was just waiting for the time limit to finish. Thanks for your help too

Comment: @w69rdy - Thanks!  @herenvardo - I did indeed forget to indicate the object in the second half of that equality test; good catch. For the `ToString()`; I missed the mention that they were already strings, but I just like to try to help the compiler out as much as possible with the return type of a ternary operator inside a lambda, just out of habit. It's unnecessary in this case. :)